# Controlling the top window program

Tags: python-3.x, select, popup, window, toplevel

I am wondering if in **Python 3.4.2** it's possible to use `EnumWindows` or `FindWindow` periodically to select a top level window, and exclude a few programs from being selected.

I have this code that I want to run and when an error message pops up, have the code press 'okay' so the code can continue to run. To control the mouse:

```
import ctypes  

SetCursorPos = ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos  
mouse_event = ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event  

def left_click(x, y, clicks=1):  
  SetCursorPos(x, y)
  for i in range(clicks):  
   mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0, 0)  
   mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)  

left_click(480, 210)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've already mentioned about `pywinauto` Python package that already encapsulated such `EnumWindows` calls and other search stuff among them. Just note that current `pywinauto 0.4.2` works on Python 2.x (32-bit) only. If you need 64-bit compatible version, get [latest development version of pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) (0.5.0+). It's already stable on Python 3.4.